# Why don't a normal computer have a CPU LED?

Tags: cpu, led

So most desktop/laptop/server computers have a HDD indicator LED, but do not have a CPU LED, why is this?

I asked a long time ago on another forum, but only a few people answered and they said "it's because CPU is always active". This didn't convince me because we have "CPU usage" in the task manager.

Now I'm playing with my Beaglebone-Black, and it does have a CPU LED: http://beagleboard.org/getting-started

So, why doesn't a normal computer have one?

Comment: It does, it's called the "power" light.

Comment: But the power light don't indicate the CPU usage.

Comment: I don't know if it would even be useful, because it would constantly be on and it can process way more tasks per second than a HDD or SSD can.

Comment: Sorry but that's not the case, if it's not useful why would a HDD LED useful, and why there's CPU usage reading in the software? Also it won't be constant on, unless you always use your CPU 100%. And it's not related to how powerful it is, it won't need a indicator just because it's powerful than HDD?

Comment: The very existence of a task manager and a cpu usage indicator is because the CPU is active. Even the CPU idle cycle is the CPU being active. The fact is: HDD LED is also a useless holdover that exists because they used to be so slow that most things actually took human-measurable time to complete and the activity light was meant to prevent human impatience. Of course back then we could hear it anyway.

Comment: The beagle board has one because they want you to know that it is working when you have no video etc: it is a hobbyist thing that probably doesn't work more often than it does. Having an inherent DEV nature, we tend to break things for fun.

Comment: Its also important to note activity indicator lights are not accurate.  Hard drive lights and network activity lights simply light up at a certain threshold.  They are almost always active.

Answer (score 5):

A modern operating system has a large quantity of background tasks that are performed every second just viewing a blank screen, the led *would* be lit almost permanently.

You might be able to calibrate the brightness to correspond to CPU usage, but with the sheer quantity of CPUs and power states it would be nearly impossible to get any meaningful information from it. 100% usage on the lowest power state would probably be less than 10% at the highest power state and your processor can change power states several hundred times a second.

You would have a light that was permanently on, but varying almost imperceptibly.  It would be difficult to get any meaningful information from because how lit the light would be would depend on the CPU utilisation which in turn would depend on the CPU clock frequency.  It would look just like a completely random flicker as the CPU cycled up and down through it's power states.  To get any meaningful information you'd probably need at least two or more LEDs to indicate processor power state, sub-states, memory controller load and so on.  As stated in the comments you'd then be looking at LEDs per core and, if hyper-threaded, per virtual core as well.  At that point you might as well have just opened up the task manger to see what your computer is doing.

Your Beaglebone by comparison has a fixed clock rate and the percent CPU usage is generally likely to be low due to the streamlined operating system, much easier to get a calibrated signal from.

Comment: +1. I'm picturing a server with an array of CPUs, with many cores, sometimes hyper-threaded. A single light would be meaningless. So the logical thing is an array of LEDs, one for each CPU. Or one for each core? Yeah, no thanks.

Comment: I hadn't even considered multi-core or hyperthreading... oh dear dog no, I'll just illuminate two million pixels just to work out what my CPU is doing, maybe have the lights be multi-colour so I can show pictures as well.... https://xkcd.com/722/

Comment: One per logical CPU (for load), 6(?) per CPU per state, and maybe a dozen per CPU for frequency. So about 76 LEDs per avarage quad core CPU. MOve for bigger or HT CPU's.

Comment: @Hennes And then you need a dedicated CPU to drive all those lights, otherwise you'll be permanently overloading the main CPU.

Comment: Well, if it load the main CPU then you could skips a few LEDs for the low-load part. Premature optimalisation for the win. :)

Comment: Make these leds in a display, give them colors, place them on the desktop and you have a monitor.... Wait, what was the question again? xD

Comment: The detection and display of disk activity can be done with simple hardware and is OS independent. In contrast the measurement of CPU usage requires reading and interpretation of raw performance data provided by an OS. Some of this is done by the OS itself and some by a utility like Task Manager. This is all very OS dependent. Alternatively it could be done within the CPU itself if the manufacturer thought it of sufficient value. And the results may not be valid for all operating systems.

Comment: Well in TV shows they _have_ all those blinking lights in computer rooms... looks cool. (yes they are all fake, I know)